# Symfony API Entity Validation

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a class with annotations for the validation.

```php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serialize;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use AppBundle\Annotation\Link;

/**
 * @Serialize\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @Serialize\AccessType(type="public_method")
 * @Serialize\AccessorOrder("custom", custom = {"id", "name", "awardType", "nominations"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AwardRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="awards")
 * @Link("self", route = "api_awards_show", params = { "id": "object.getId()" })
 */
class Award extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @Serialize\Expose()
     * @Serialize\Type(name="string")
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a name for the Award")
     * @Assert\Length(min="3", max="255")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Serialize\Expose()
     * @Serialize\Type(name="AppBundle\Entity\AwardType")
     * @Serialize\MaxDepth(depth=2)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\AwardType",
     *     inversedBy="awards"
     * )
     */
    private $awardType;

    /**
     * @Serialize\Expose()
     * @Serialize\Type(name="ArrayCollection<AppBundle\Entity\Nomination>")
     * @Serialize\MaxDepth(depth=2)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Nomination",
     *     mappedBy="award"
     * )
     */
    private $nominations;
}
```

I then validate that entity with the following:

```php
    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($entity);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        $apiProblem = new ApiProblem(
            400,
            ApiProblem::TYPE_VALIDATION_ERROR
        );

        $apiProblem->set('errors', ['testing', 'array']);

        throw new ApiProblemException($apiProblem);
    }

    $this->save($entity);
```

This works fine the problem is that i cant get the information on which fields have errors and their error message. $errors in this case seems to be of an unknown type which i cant seem to get the error messages for any fields.

How do i get the error messages of that object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the exact messages of the errors like this:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($entity);

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    $formattedErrors = [];
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        $formattedErrors[$error->getPropertyPath()] = [
            'message' => sprintf('The property "%s" with value "%s" violated a requirement (%s)', $error->getPropertyPath(), $error->getInvalidValue(), $error->getMessage());
        ];
    }

    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($formattedErrors, 400);
}
```

For example, that could output:

```
[
    'field1' => 'The property "field1" with value "" violated a requirement (Cannot be null)',
    // ...
]
```

Comment: will this get me all the errors or will it it stop on the first error?

Comment: Thank you for the info its much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. if it doesn't bother you, can you give me the reason of why you don't up-voted my answer ? If I can improve it, it could be helpful for people with the same issue.

Comment: Oh Im sorry i really don't understand the voting to well i thought just accepting it does what its supposed to do. My apologies. I think i just up-voted it now. I hope i haven't been messing other answer up.

Comment: No problem :) It's effectively not automatic and you're not the first. It's encouraging for other people that could read the answer and for the answer's owner to write other answers. Thank you for the up-vote ! Don't hesitate to go on your previous questions to vote those that helped you, it will be really appreciated.